# How to modify Arduino boards.txt to support new MCUs

Tags: avrdude, atmega328

In [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/arduino-boot-loader-problem), it was mentioned that to get the Arduino IDE to support an ATmega328 (only the ATmega328P is supported):

> I should mention the Arduino way of doing this, is to create a new
>   boards.txt file with this chip and add (not change) the avrdude.conf
>   file. This will allow programing either from selecting the correct
>   board. but that is another subject.

After a great deal of research in the past, and attempted modifications to boards.txt and avrdude.conf, I arrived at the conclusion that the Toolchain doesn't support the ATmega328 therefore the changes will have no effect.

Can anyone confirm that they have successfully found a way to make these changes, so we can avoid the need for a work-around?

Comment: what is the error? the same as in that other post you link to?

Comment: See these links: http://computerpr0n.com/2012/03/burning-arduino-bootrom-on-an-atmega328-pu/ | http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=58670.0 | http://www.instructables.com/id/Bootload-an-ATmega328/step6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, Note that the Arduino IDE is behind on many of the tools. In this case avrdude and its conf file, along with avr-gcc

**First:**

```
.\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf
```

needs to support the m328 in addition to m328p. This can be done by either updating

```
.\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avrdude.exe
```

to something like [avrdude-6.1-svn-20131205-mingw32](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avrdude/). along with replacing the conf file with the new one

```
.\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf
```

file that has both m328 along with the m328p. Note 6.1 supports a parent method, making it easy to duplicate chips with different signatures. Or use existing 5.11 and add to its

```
.\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf
```

file by duplicating the entire m328p section and renaming the new entry to "m328" along with the correct signature.

**Second:**

avr-gcc need to be updated to support compiling both the m328p and m328. Yes, it just a semantic thing. But the next part will send either ATmega328p or ATmega328 to both gcc and dude. which both need to support it. One can simply copy over

```
.\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\
```

with the new tool chain. I used [avr-gcc-4.8_2013-03-06_mingw32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mobilechessboar/files/avr-gcc%20snapshots%20%28Win32%29/)

**Third:**

replace the following line in boards.txt

```
uno.build.mcu=atmega328p
```

with

```
## Arduino ATmega328P
## ---------------------------------------------
uno.menu.cpu.atmega328p=ATmega328P
uno.menu.cpu.atmega328p.build.mcu=atmega328p

## Arduino ATmega328
## ---------------------------------------------
uno.menu.cpu.atmega328=ATmega328
uno.menu.cpu.atmega328.build.mcu=atmega328
```

This will add an option to the IDE when UNO is selected for either chip. And subsequently send the correct MCU to both the compiler and avrdude.

---

**Proof:**

Below are the verbose output of the IDE with the above changes. Note the -mmcu and -p for both options. As a real unit is was not connected it yielded the "not in sync" error. Where this shows it all works.

```
C:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=156 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp\sketch_jul31a.cpp -o C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp\sketch_jul31a.cpp.o 
...
C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp/sketch_jul31a.cpp.hex 

Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
C:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp/sketch_jul31a.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
...
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

---

```
C:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=156 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp\sketch_jul31a.cpp -o C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp\sketch_jul31a.cpp.o 
...
C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp/sketch_jul31a.cpp.hex 

Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
C:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\projects\Arduino\arduino-1.5.6-r2/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328 -carduino -PCOM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6597836883576934105.tmp/sketch_jul31a.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
...
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: One draw back, may be that the new compiler will have some issues on poorly written code and libraries. IDE 1.0 and early complained with latest versions of gcc. Mostly bad coding that is easily corrected. Where I do believe for the addition of the ARMs these have been corrected. At least in the IDE's core libraries.

Comment: I'm curious if you can use uno.menu.cpu.atmega328=ATmega328
uno.menu.cpu.atmega328.build.mcu=atmega328p to get it to build for a 328p with the old compiler, but flash as a 328 (ie, looking for that signature).

Comment: I looked at that first. The \arduino-1.5.6-r2\hardware\arduino\avr\platform.txt uses {build.mcu} in both the compile and avrdude. Alternatively (and not pretty) would be to define a ...build.mcu_upload in the boards.txt and replace the "-p{build.mcu}" with -p{build.mcu_upload}. However, this would require that all entries in the boards.txt have the added build.mcu_upload" added. (not very clean). This does have the advantage of supporting both chips and use the stock provided compiler.

Comment: looks like IDE 1.5.7 BETA, has just upgraded both AVR-GCC and AVR-DUDE to the latest. Which include support for both m328 and m328p or above mentioned Steps 1 and 2. Step 3 is still needed.